# Unable to intregrate Dropbox in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, spring, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, c#-5.0

I am trying to intregate drop box in my app .
Since Dropbox didn't provide anhy api's for windows phone or .net ,I went with [springframework](http://www.springframework.net/) Thirdparty API  .

According to there [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/social-dropbox/refdoc/api.html)

```
string consumerKey = "..."; // The application's consumer key
string consumerSecret = "..."; // The application's consumer secret
string accessToken = "..."; // The access token granted after OAuth authorization
string accessTokenSecret = "..."; // The access token secret granted after OAuth authorization
IDropbox dropbox = new DropboxTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, AccessLevel.Full);
```

DropBoxTemplate() =>

```
IDropbox dropbox = new DropboxTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, AccessLevel.Full);
```

Takes the following as parameter :

```
consumerKey     //i am asuming it is appKey
consumerSecret //i am asuming it is appSectret
```

this two i know as i created the app in dropbox.developer website

```
but i dont Know the other two  ,that is  :
accessToken          //Generated on call of access_Token_Request   i guess
accessTokenSecret   //Generated on call of access_Token_Secret_Request   i guess
```

My question is how to get/assign values to two of these (accessToken & accessTokenSecret) variables in C# in Windows Phone

Comment: Can Any One help me out here

Comment: @crea7or  so according to you , app key is accessToken and app secret is accessToken Secret ...is that what you mean to tell??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` the application wide values that you [can take here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps). `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` the user keys to access the specified user account (after authorization in DropBox service).

Comment: so app key is accessToken and app secret is accessToken Secret ...is that what you mean to tell??

Comment: Yes, try this scheme.